# Requirements not being included in template

Tags: templates, silverstripe

I've got a controller that has some basic functions and a basic template:

```
class CMSController extends Page_Controller {

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        Requirements::javascript("cms/javascript/asdf.js");
    }

    public function index(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
        Requirements::javascript("cms/javascript/asdf.js");
        return $this->renderWith(array("CMSHomePage", "Page"));
    }
}
```

However the javascript isn't added to the template as expected. Do I have to pass it to the template via the `renderWith()` or do I have to add something to the template to allow it to render? (It's just a basic html file with a `<script>` in it.

Comment: Your JS file has HTML inside it?

Comment: Nope, that one doesn't exist and was looking for a 404. I have tried ones that exist and they don't show up either.

Comment: Flushing your cache/manifest in between each request?

Comment: Yup /dev/build?flush=1

Comment: Maybe your path is wrong. Usually javascript files will go in /mysite/javascript/ or /themes/themename/javascript/

Comment: But I should get a 404 if that was the case.

Comment: @Rudiger no atm not AFAIK, it fails silently

Comment: @munomono Not sure if other things I've changed caused it to work again but you're right, it fails silently and my `Requirements` are working again. You could make that the answer and I'll mark it correct.